# Reusing existing provider within Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an Angular component (with child components) that can be used across multiple modules. The child components have a dependency on a variable number of injectable services.

Each of the child components has their own `providers: [...]` setting that allows the component to load in a new instance of the provider. However, I would prefer if the component were to reuse an existing instance of the provider if it existed.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules?

Comment: This is basically the approach we're falling back on, but the nature of the child comps is that we'd end up putting A LOT of injectables at a module level that may never be used

Comment: ...and? If that's very troubling to you, you can have more than one shared module.

Comment: Sure, I could. My question is whether I can advise a component to use a new provider if or reuse an existing.

Comment: No, it's about where they're defined. If they're component-level providers, a new instance will be created for each component.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands there is no way to advise a component to reuse an existing provider or tell it to use a new one.

Generally, when you want to share components across multiple feature modules, it is suggested to have a "Shared Module" that declares and exports all of the components you want to be shareable. That shared module is also where you should provide any services that it's contained components might need.

You would then import this shared module into any other feature module where you want that component to be shared.

For more info on application structure, take a look at the Angular Style Guide (mostly written by John Papa):
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module